# Quick question: How to set a cookie that will expire after 90days in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I wish to set a cookie that expires in 90 days using PHP, how could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setcookie(name, value, time()+60*60*24*90);
```

This will set the cookie for 90 Days.

Answer (score 3):

cookie expirations are set in seconds: so 60*60*24*90 would be 90 days

```
setcookie("MyCookie", $value, time()+(60*60*24*90));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', strtotime('NOW+90DAYS'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', time() + 7776000);
```

Check out the documentation for more details - http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+7776000);
```

Comment: Gah! Thanks; but I can't even blame Wolfram Alpha this time :)